# $A_i \cap A_j$ has $i + j$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have the next problem:

Find sets $A_1,...,A_n$, such that $|A_i\cap A_j|=i+j$ for $i,j \leq n$ with $i \neq j$

I've tried to solve the problem but I just can't imagine the way to do it. I know the solution by an induction construction in the infinite case, but the finite case is not clear to me. I don't want just say something like "this works in the infinite case, so in the finite would do it too".

Comment: If your "infinite case" is an infinite sequence $A_1,A_2,\dots$ such that $|A_i\cup A_j|=i+j$ for $i\ne j$, then just take the first $n$ elements of that sequence.

Comment: Your closing remark makes me suspect that by "the finite case" you intended to require that each set $A_i, i = 1,\ldots,n$ is finite.  However the one-line problem statement doesn't include that restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each pair $(i,j)$ with $1\leq i<j\leq n$ let $B_{i,j}$ be a set such that $B_{i,j}$ has size $i+j$ so that all the $B_{i,j}$ are disjoint.

Make $A_l$ be the union of all the $B_{i,j}$ such that $l=i$ or $l=j$.

For $i < j$ we have $A_i \cap A_j = B_{i,j}$.

Comment: Is not necessary say that $ B_{ij} = B_{ji}$?

Comment: We only define it for pairs with $i<j$

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach with induction assuming it works for $n$ you can extend it to $n+1$ by adding $n+1+i$ distinct, not in any $A_j, j\neq i$ elements into $A_i$ and make $A_{n+1}$ the union of all the elements you added.

Example $A_1=A_2=\{1,2,3\}$, then for $3$ we'd take $B_1=\{1,2,3\}\cup\{4,5,6,7\},B_2=\{1,2,3\}\cup\{8,9,10,11,12\},B_3=\{4,5,6,7\}\cup \{8,9,10,11,12\}$